# Is there a way in bash/powershell to automatically include a word in a command based on context?

Tags: bash, git, powershell, shell, autocomplete

Currently, when inside git repos, I type `git status`. Is there any way for my shell to understand this is a git repo and automatically append `git` to relevant commands?

e.g.,

```sh
# bash example
# before
git status

# after
status # "status" isn't a registered command, but "git status" is, so bash uses the latter
```

I'd probably only want this enabled when I'm in a repo, but is there any way to get functionality similar to this in any of the popular shells?

I recognize this isn't always preferred or the best idea, but it could save me from typing a word.

Comment: How does your question relate to powershell? If you want to discuss the same problem for two different languages (bash vs. powershell), please ask two different questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is what aliases were invented for in bash. You'd add a line to your bashrc that looked like this:

```sh
alias status='git status'
```

If you'd like, you could add one for every git subcommand you ran frequently:

```sh
alias commit='git commit'
alias checkout='git checkout'
alias add='git add'
alias push='git push'
alias pull='git pull'
alias config='git config'
```

Your environment is your own, and if you wanna make a shorthand for git commands, you're free to do so!

Also, these aliases will pass any arguments to the underlying command. So if you write:

```sh
commit -m "My message"
```

This will translate to `git commit -m "My message"`.

These aliases should be added to a file like the `.bashrc` file in your home directory, if one exists.

[See here for a more in-depth explanation of aliases.](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/)